# permutations and probabilty

Tags: permutations

> In a certain country, the number plate on a car consists of any 3 letters of the alphabet (the first letter is always a "K" or a "G"), followed by any 3 digits (0 to 9) and a alphabet. For a car chosen at random, what is the probability that the number plate starts with a "G" and ends with an odd digit and a non-vowel?

The number plate starts with a ’K’, so there is only 1 choice for the first letter, and ends with an even digit, so there are 5 choices for the last digit (1,3,5,7,9), 5 vowels and 10 possible choices for each of the other digits.

Therefore Number of events=  Total number of possible number plates=  Probability=

Comment: Hi, I broke up your text a bit for readability and highlighted the question. Are you trying to find the inverse case? or did you just lose track of which letter was specified to start?

Answer (score 0):

$$n(S) = 2 \times 10 \times 10 \times 10 \times 26$$

$$n(A) = 1 \times 10 \times 10 \times 5 \times 21$$ ( assuming "y" is not a vowel)

so $$P(A) = \frac{n(A)}{n(S)} = \frac 12  \times \frac{5}{10} \times \frac{21}{26} $$